# Why do sperm have centrioles and do female eggs cells even have centrioles?

Tags: cytoskeleton

I was just wondering why it is that sperm have centrioles underneath the acrosome, but that also prompted a thought as to whether eggs have them too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oocytes do not have centrioles. During fertilization, the centrioles of the sperm become the centrioles of the zygote. Only one pair is needed, as there is only one cell (i.e. zygote) right after fertilization.

Comment: Please add a link, summary, and/or citation for a source to back up your claims.

Answer (score -1):

During fertilization the centrosme inter the ooplasm with the sperm nucleus,  if the oocyte still keep its centrosme there will result 2 centrosme in zygote with 4 centriole. Each one will migrate to pole of cell and produce 4 poles not two and the 4 daughter cells of one division will have one centriole in this case through mitosis will shut off.

Comment: Please add some reliable references to this answer :) If you have any questions or concerns about answering questions, please see the Help Center https://biology.stackexchange.com/help